# Modify <param> value from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visio

I am trying to embed a visio doc in an aspx page using the following code

```
<OBJECT classid="CLSID:279D6C9A-652E-4833-BEFC-312CA8887857" 
codebase="http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/2/452f8090-413f-408f-83c0-edd66db786ee/vviewer.exe" 
id="viewer1" width="100%" height="100"> 
<param name="BackColor" value="16777120">
<param name="AlertsEnabled" value="1">
<param name="ContextMenuEnabled" value="1">
<param name="GridVisible" value="0">
<param name="HighQualityRender" value="1">
<param name="PageColor" value="16777215">
<param name="PageVisible" value="1">
<param name="PropertyDialogEnabled" value="1">
<param name="ScrollbarsVisible" value="1">
<param name="ToolbarVisible" value="1">
<param name="SRC" value="http://wssxxxx/Shared%20Documents/Yukon%20Timeline.vsd">
<param name="CurrentPageIndex" value="0">
<param name="Zoom" value="-1">
</object>
```

i need to modify the `value` parameter `SRC` from code , how do i go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it run at server:

```
<param name="SRC" id="prmSrc" runat="server" />
```

And in your code behind:

```
prmSrc.Attributes["value"] = "...";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh.aspx):

```
<param name="SRC" value="<%:MyValue%>">
```

Or this (if not using .NET 4.0):

```
<param name="SRC" value="<%=Server.HtmlEncode(MyValue)%>">
```

In your page, you can create a string property called `MyValue`:

```
public string MyValue { get; set; }
```

And set it in code to whatever you need:

```
// In page_load
MyValue = "http://example.com/code_blocks.vsd";
```

Comment: gave me an error `Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'`

Comment: The `<%: MyValue %>` syntax will only work in ASP.NET 4. Try `<%= Server.HtmlEncode(MyValue) %>` instead.

Comment: @Shark - that is new to .NET 4.0, so will not work on earlier versions. Use `<%=%>` instead of `<%:%>`.